# google charts onclick lightbox

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

i am using google charts, for every pie section i want user to be able to click on that and open another window as light box showing relevant data (passing on querystring values), but the below code simply opens another html widow

here is my code

```
function selectHandler() {
    var selection = chart1.getSelection();
    var row = selection[0].row;
    var ColName = data1.getValue(row, 0);
    var ColValue = data1.getValue(row, 1);
    window.open('http://localhost:5555/folder1/Visit.aspx?ColName=' + ColName + '&ColValue=' + ColValue, '_blank', "class=shadowbox");
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select', selectHandler);
```

Comment: Of course it opens another HTML window, you call `window.open` that does exactly this. If you want to display Lightbox popup, download some framework and use a different code.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(...);
```

Will open a new window for sure.

You need to use a lightbox plugin to show a lightbox popup.